# Question related to splitting of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, pseudoinverse, generalized-inverse

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n }; A=U-V$ be a splitting such that $R(A)=R(U), N(A)=N(U)$ where $R(A),N(A)$ denote the range space and null space $A.$

Definition of Moore-Penrose inverse of a matrix

> $A^\dagger y=x$  if $Ax=y, x \in R(A^T)$ and
> $A^\dagger y=0$ if $y \in N(A^T).$

[For what vectors does $A^+ A v = v$, where $A^+$ is the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverseof $A$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4856866/for-what-vectors-does-a-a-v-v-where-a-is-the-moore-penrose-pseudoinve)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse

> Doubt: Let $A=U-V$ be a splitting such that $R(A)=R(U), N(A)=N(U)$ Since $R(A)=R(U) \implies R(V) \subseteq R(U)$ Thus $UU^\dagger V=V$ Hence $A=U-UU^\dagger V=U(I-U^\dagger V).$
> Claim: $(I-U^\dagger V)$ is non-singular

My approach: Assume $U^\dagger V x=x;$ for some $0 \ne x \in \mathbb{R}^n$
$\implies x\in R(U^\dagger)=R(U^T)=R(A^T)---(*)$ and $UU^\dagger Vx=Ux\implies Vx-Ux=0 \implies Ax=0 \implies x\in N(A)---(**)$

From (*) and (**) we can say that $x=0$ since $x\in R(A^T)$ and $x \in N(A).$

Hence $(I-U^\dagger V)$ is non-singular.

Is this proof is correct?

Thanks in advanced.